# Swift - How to run 2 actions non-simultaneously (in linear mode) for two different SKNodes in the same function

Tags: swift, skaction, sknode

I have a function in which I need to run 2 actions one after another.
e.g.

```
func foo()
{
     ..........
     if someConditions
     {
          node1.runAction1
          node2.runAction2
     }
}
```

It seems that swift is running those actions simultaneously.
And that's exactly what I do not want to happen in my game.
I want action2 to start after action1 is finished.

**What should I have to do?**
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a completion handler when calling `node1.runAction` that will start `node2`'s action when `node1`'s action is compelete. For example:

```
node1.runAction(action1) {
    node2.runAction(action2)
}
```

**Edit**

In response to your comment, here is a possible solution: Define `runAction1` like so (I'm assuming `runAction1` is a method on one of your classes).

```
func runAction1(completion: () -> Void) {
    // ...
    self.runAction(action, completion: completion)
}
```

Then use this like so:

```
node1.runAction1(completion: node2.runAction2)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually my post has a kind of a leak. Well, those two actions specified as node1.runAction1 and the next one are in separate functions. In fact I am calling func1  - animateTheFirstBall() and func2  - animateTheSecondBall()   instead of those node1.runAction1 ant the other.

Comment: Yes, please. I could very much appreciate a brief example as I am not using closures (that's what you are speaking of, I guess)  quite often. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: Yes, it works great. That is ending my long array of sleepless nights. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Glad I could help! Good luck with your project! Also, you mentioned you're unfamiliar with closures - I would really recommend looking into them if you've got some time, since they ate useful in so many places :) Apple's *The Swift Programming Language* covers them in detail.